# How to filter dates using dtpicker in listview with database

Tags: vb6

I'm creating a payroll system, and I want to search the date in listview using dtpicker and calculate the number of daily rate,Please help me guys

[image]

```
   Private Sub sumBtn_Click()
   Dim objItem As ListItem
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim lngDailyRate As Long

Dim iDateSubitemIndex As Integer
Dim iDailyRateSubitemIndex As Integer

iDateSubitemIndex = 6
iDailyRateSubitemIndex = 7

For iCounter = 1 To Listview1.ListItems.Count

    ' Get List Item
    Set objItem = Listview1.ListItems.Item(iCounter)

    ' Check Date
    If CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) >= DTPicker3 And CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) >= DTPicker4 Then
    lngDailyRate = lngDailyRate + CLng(objItem.SubItems(iDailyRateSubitemIndex))

    End If
Next

    MsgBox "Daily Rate for " & DTPicker3 & " to " & DTPicker4 & " is " & 
  lngDailyRate

  End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the listview contains? What is "the number of daily rate"?

Comment: Hi sir thank you for your response, i just recently edited my post I attached image

Comment: You want your listview to only show employees who worked during the timeframe  defined in the DTR area?

Comment: Yes sir , and get the sum of daily_rate column is that possible ?

Comment: The data in the listview comes from a database? If so, you can add a WHERE clause in your SELECT statement to specify the date range and also create a SUM column that sums up the daily rate column.

Comment: I don't get it , can you give me a hint or example code sir ?

Comment: If you are retrieving the items in the listview from a database, you can use SQL to filter out the records directly. You can look up SQL SELECT on the Internet and find examples of how to filter records using a WHERE clause. For example: `SELECT SUM (DAILY_RATE) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE LOGD='9/11/2019'`

Comment: Thank you for sharing your  idea sir , Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can sum up your DAILY_RATE column using just the data in the ListView:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim objItem As ListItem
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim lngDailyRate As Long

    Dim iDateSubitemIndex As Integer
    Dim iDailyRateSubitemIndex As Integer

    ' Update these to reflect your ListView
    iDateSubitemIndex = 1
    iDailyRateSubitemIndex = 2

    For iCounter = 1 To ListView1.ListItems.Count

        ' Get List Item
        Set objItem = ListView1.ListItems.item(iCounter)

        ' Check Date
        If CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) = DTPicker1 Then
            lngDailyRate = lngDailyRate + CLng(objItem.SubItems(iDailyRateSubitemIndex))
        End If

    Next

    MsgBox "Daily Rate for " & DTPicker1 & " is " & lngDailyRate

End Sub
```

Please update the two SubitemIndex variables to match the columns in your ListView. These are used to retrieve the data from the correct column.

Comment: Thank  you so much sir . God bless, how to mark this solved ?

Comment: It works sir but it only calculate two dates in dtpicker, if i select 09-12-19 to 09-12-15 it only add two dates , I want the output to be added 12,13,14,15 dates = 1680

Comment: It works sir but it only calculate two dates in dtpicker, if i select 09-12-19 to 09-12-15 it only add two dates , I want the output to be added 12,13,14,15 dates = 1680

Comment: Simply change the "Check Date" condition to compare using `CDate() >= DTPicker1 And CDate() <= DTPicker2` instead of `CDate() = DTPicker1`.

Comment: If CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) >= DTPicker3 Then
        lngDailyRate = lngDailyRate + CLng(objItem.SubItems(iDailyRateSubitemIndex))
        End If 
like this sir ?

Comment: I really dont know how to use Cdate sir

Comment: `If CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) >= DTPickerStart And CDate(objItem.SubItems(iDateSubitemIndex)) <= DTPickerEnd Then`

Comment: MsgBox "Daily Rate for " & DTPickerstart & " is " & lngDailyRate sir in this line i will add dtpickerend ?

Comment: `MsgBox "Daily Rate for " & DTPickerStart & " to " & DTPickerEnd & " is " & lngDailyRate`.

Replace `DTPickerStart` and `DTPickerEnd` with whatever your DTPicker controls are named.

Comment: Please post your code in the question so we can see what you have written so far.

Comment: if I select the same date for start and end date 9/19/19  - 9/9/19 it gives me the correct total amount but when i select the correct end date it only gives me the amount of the end date

Comment: Both your comparisons have `>=`. One needs to be different.

Comment: Sir how can i retrieve data from database to listview to filter out the records

Comment: You should post a new question for that, the topic is different enough.